# Does baseball have an equivalent of "six and out"?

Tags: rules, cricket, baseball

In [backyard cricket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backyard_cricket), an informal version of normal cricket, you can get "six and out", which means that you score six runs but you're out, if you hit the ball outside of the playing area.

Do any informal versions of baseball have a similar rule?

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of this existing in any baseball league.  However, in some slow pitch softball leagues there are variations of two rules that relate:

1. If the batter hits a home run that clears the fence, he/she is out.  A variation of this is that after `x` amount of homeruns are hit in a game/inning by a player/team, any further homeruns count as an out.
2. There is something called a *slaughter rule*.  You can actually find this in some baseball little leagues.  A team may only score `x` amount of runs in an inning/game, or a team may only be leading the other team by `x` amount of runs at the end of an inning; and if that total is passed, the inning/game is over.

Comment: Wikipedia link for "slaughter rule", also known as a mercy rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercy_rule

Comment: Is there a name for rule 1?

Comment: If anything, *home-and-out* would make the most sense. @AndrewGrimm